# Image style is not rendering

Tags: 7, media

My field_image is not rendering on user-profile.tpl. I have the following code (two different ways to render for testing):

```
    $image = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_image');
    $output = field_view_value('user', $user, 'field_image', $image[0], array(
      'type' => 'image',
      'settings' => array(
        'image_style' => 'header_image_160x160',
      ),
    ));
    print render($output);
```

This produces the following in html:

```
<img src="https://coinme.io/sites/default/files/styles/header_image_160x160/public?itok=f31sbmSd" width="160" height="160" alt="">
```

I get the dead image logo. It is missing the final part of the file structure. And this is how I normally render:

```
$to_render = field_view_field('user', $user, 'field_image', array('settings' => array('image_style' => 'header_image_160x160'))); print render($to_render);
```

This is showing the default image, even though the image does exist:

https://coinme.io/sites/default/files/styles/header_image_160x160/public/images/profile/profile-large.png?itok=rb-2qFOw

I have the same field in a content type which is rendering correctly (only difference being the $user user -> $node node.

```
<?php $to_render = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_image', array('settings' => array('image_style' => 'header_image_160x160'))); print render($to_render);?>
```

So it appears that when using user-profile specifically is the issue. I have also tried adding a new field type and same effect. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Paul.

Comment: Are you sure `$user` is in scope and that the field name is `field_image`? It looks like one of those things is causing the actual filename to be unavailable.

Comment: @DavidThomas I just came to the same conclusion. It didn't occur to me until I did a print_r($user) and got my logged in user. Thank you for getting involved.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple: `$user` is the logged-in user; since the logged-in user didn't have a profile image, I got the default image.

Elsewhere on the page, I wasn't using `$user`, but all the variables whose ID started with `$field_`, so it looked like I was using the right variable. This fixed it.

```php
$account = $elements['#account'];
```

Then, I updated `$user` to `$account`.

```php
$to_render = field_view_field('user', $account, 'field_image', array('settings' => array('image_style' => 'header_image_160x160'))); print render($to_render);
```